# How can I modify the Daylight Saving Time of my timezone on Windows Mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, dst

My phone, running Windows Mobile 6, has suddenly decided to drop an hour every time I hook it up to my PC. I tried playing with the timezone settings in the Control Panel, to no avail.

I've come to the conclusion the heart of the problem is in the Daylight Saving configuration of my timezone.

I could not find any utilities to let me edit this on Windows Mobile (ala `tzedit` in Windows). I've decided to write something of my own, but I cannot find the right keywords to search for! All the variations I can think of for "Windows mobile" and "daylight savings" keep coming back to the changes made in 2007 to the U.S.A DST, and not to an API!

Does anyone have any suggestions which functions I should be looking for? I'd like to write this in C#, but P/Invoke should let me access the regular API stuff, I hope.

UPDATE: I ended up writing the application myself, using the `TimeZoneInformation` function as suggested below. Thanks!

Another UPDATE [about a 2 weeks later]: If you need something like this, I put the program and source code online at http://shalom.craimer.org/projects/. I hope this save somebody 5 minutes or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also pinvoke the [TimeZoneInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450660.aspx) functions in case you don't want/can't use the OpenNetCF framework.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [TimeZoneInformation](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/081758af-13a4-42ee-64e0-5a1dec1c979d.htm) class of OpenNetCF.

Answer (score 1):

In my windows mobile phone (european, similar to at&t blackjack II), there is a setting to to that.
Otherwise, disable temporarily the setting in ActiveSync to update the time everytimes you sync it

Answer (score 0):

It some time ago, but if i remember correctly all the TimeZones and which one is currently active is stored within the registry on WinCE.

Just make a search for a key containing *TimeZone* and you should find it quite easy.

Comment: They are, but they are encoded in some format I was too lazy to try and reverse engineer. I just ended up using the Windows Mobile's API instead...

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the patch both on your desktop PC (the Operating System and Outlook) and your [mobile PC device](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/downloads/microsoft/daylight-savings-update.mspx). The link has details about how to do this.

After this it will show the correct time. You may have to adjust any future appointments on your mobile PC that were automatically shifted if they were made on days that now have a different time due to daylight saving. Check these carefully so you are on time!

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to know how to modify the DST setting myself since I live in a country (Israel) which changes the DST start/end dates once every few years. What's worse, the dates chosen aren't dates in the Gregorian-calendar format, but dates on the Hebrew calendar, so they aren't the same date on the Gregorian calendar every year.